# Pandas resample .ffill()

Tags: python, pandas, function, time

I have data in minutes I want to collect them per day and per hour without adding the sum because it is an increment if the total increases we add a 1
I tried the function ffill() pandas resample but it returns me this :
[enter image description here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to say what kind of aggregation you are doing over your new resampled period.

If you just want to get the sum for each day:
df2.resample('D').sum()

Then if you want to fill the NaN you can apply your transformation of choice ie ffill